# How can I save variable values across program close/reopen?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

basically all I want to do is code my project so that it stores any saved variables for the next time the program is run. At the moment once I close and reopen the program it obviously resets any variables. Is there any simple way to do this (please bear in mind, i'm very new at programming

Il give you an example. If I have a simple program that when I press a button it adds 1 to a counter. Now next time I open that program and press the button again I want to add to the previous counter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to save the values (to file or registry) before the app closes, and load them when it starts.

Comment: which component or code should help me ?

Comment: There are components but you are supposed to ask for them here. JEDI has a settings component. You could save in an INI file, a JSON file, an XML file etc. Or save to the registry.

Comment: 1. Make an inventory of all the data you want to save. 2. Depending on the amount and structure choose for file storage (XML, INI) or registry. 3. Google Delphi + your chosen technology 4. Start building 5. Come back with specific questions if needed

Comment: Worth noting that saving values to a SQLLite database is sometimes useful too, particularly if your state data is more complex than simple counters and the like. SQLLite is very easy to use with Delphi too

Comment: Don't listen to them :p Use `file` type! (read `File types` topic in the online documentation)

Answer (score 3):

You can have two simple routines that save and load from the registry like this:

```
uses   SysUtils, Registry;
...
function RegistryLoadString(const sKey, sItem, sDefVal: string ): string;
var
  reg: TRegIniFile;
begin
  reg := TRegIniFile.Create(sKey);
  try
    result := reg.ReadString('', sItem, sDefVal);
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure RegistrySaveString(const sKey, sItem, sVal: string);
var
  reg: TRegIniFile;
begin
  reg := TRegIniFile.Create(sKey);
  try
    reg.WriteString('', sItem, sVal + #0);
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

On application load you can use them like this:

```
counter := StrToInt(RegistryLoadString( 'My program', 'counter', '0' ));
```

And on application exit you will save the counter like:

```
RegistrySaveString( 'My program', 'counter', IntToStr(counter) );
```

Comment: Aren't you double null terminating